# Hostname not resolving

Tags: links, sitecore-managed-cloud

I have issues with `Sitecore Azure PaaS` from `Sitecore Managed Cloud` as below.

1. We have `red-shield` which is security shielding for request where we have configured `prod domain` which is like `prd.xyz.com`
2. Then we have Azure web app from managed cloud which has custom domain with name `prd-service.xyz.com`
3. We mapped this with DNS. So if go and use `prd.xyz.com` it goes properly.
4. But there are few cases where on the pages if we click buttons it is picking up `prd-service.xyz.com`.
5. We have all the settings right for `Link manager` and `sitedefinition`.
6. So need a way how I can tackle with any setting for the entire application which will force domain which in the request and in `site-definition`.

Comment: Sounds like either bad config in red-shield or bad config in `<sites>` config

Comment: Would be great to update your question with your site definition and also link manager to see the settings that has been made

Comment: Welcome to SSE @Nikil . I am Assuming this is a SXA Site, Please share snapshot of your Sites item

Comment: Did you set targetHostName in your site-node in <sites> config? Had a similar problem a few days ago and targetHostName fixed it for me.

Comment: @MarkGibbons <sites> node in config is configured properly no issues with that as I am working with Sitecore Managed cloud team they also cross verified this.

Comment: @PeterProcházka Link manager code is also decent no issues on this only the thing is even I setup targethostname to required one it is picking up what is there in Azure binding.

Comment: @AbhayDhar  This is simple scaled Sitecore website with EXM and JSS.

Comment: @AnnaBründel  Yes already done this, still link manager picking what is configured Azure web app.

Comment: I have something like below if you thing that is wrong please let me know 

patch:before="site[@name='website']" hostName="prd.xyz.com|prd-service.xyz.com" targetHostName="prd.xyz.com"

Comment: Hi All, I got the answer for this we created a txt record in DNS for mapping actual domain and red shield and added actual domain on Azure web app which we want to use so Sitecore is now resolving it properly. This mapping is not a simple DNS export created a complex rule for this, So I will suggest if you get same thing please work with network expoert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long discussion with Redshield and DNS Provider we got the answer to this issue which is as below.

1. We asked DNS provider to create the TXT record for Azure Webapp.
2. We asked Redshield to point to DNS for only TXT entry created.
3. Then we added the actual domain which we wanted to use.
4. And now it is working properly.

**Analysis of Mistakes:**

1. Yes as mentioned it was wrong configuration from Redshield side.
2. We can had a more analysis for this before configuring to Sitecore Azure PaaS.
3. Always follow the instruction given by Sitecore best practices.
4. In this particular case always configure actual domain which you want to server on 
   web-app itself.